# AutoIT - why CTRL+o is not submitted?

Tags: windows, autoit

I am trying to send <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> but it is not working

```
Send("{rCTRL down}{o down}{o up}{rCTRL up}")
```

Comment: Why not just `Send("^o")`? Otherwise you might need to break that up into multiple `Send()` calls. Also autoit and ahk are two different languages. Which are you trying to use?

Comment: I tried following but not working at all: Send("{LCTRL}")
Send("o")
Send("^o")
Send("^O")

Comment: Using AHK or autoit? And which version? `send("^o")` works without issue for me in an old version of autoitv3.

Comment: https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/ Latest version: v3.3.14.2. very strange not working, when i do brute force oce ^o then sometimes its working sometimes not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why but only following working:

```
Run("GUI_ofhell_OK_wait_let_me_screw_you_up.exe")
Sleep(500)
Send("{CTRLDOWN}")
Send("{o down}")
Sleep(500)
Send("{o up}")
Send("{CTRLUP}")
```

Comment: some applications (especially games) don't react on "keypress" but on "key-is-down", which may casuse timing problems. There should only be one `sleep` neccessary: the one between "o-down" and "o-up". try with `sleep 100`, that should be more than enough.